# npm start install my package, but i'm running my project with yarn start

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

If I installed some package with NPM it will work and recognize it if I run my project with yarn start instead npm start?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will still work after all the required packages are installed.

But you should not switch package Managers like that since you will generate two lock files if you use both to install packages. npm generates the `package-lock.json` and yarn will generate the `yarn.lock` file. I recommend you to stay with one or switch completely.

In runtime, it does not make any difference if you use yarn or npm.
`npm run start` and `yarn start` will do exactly the same.

Comment: Hi @Lalaluka, If you are familiar with Vue, can you tell is it okay to create a Vue project with `npm init vue@latest` and then continue with `yarn`?